# Ways to approximate functions using polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Other than Taylor's theorem what other methods can be used to approximate a function that ultimately reduces it down to a polynomial?

Comment: There is a lot out there, just look at any numerics book. Some classical examples are splines, polynomial interpolation...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial could be relevant